# Predicting single image in tensorflow object detection

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection, predict

I have trained a model for object detection using [tensorflow object detection](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/running_locally.md) repository.

Now while evaluating the [default way](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/eval.py) is to read from a `record` file using `tf.contrib.slim.parallel_reader`

I want to read the images directly using file system and get the prediction for the image. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have a look on this  https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb, here a frozen model is used, but you can use normal ckpt with minor changed logic to use image instead of tfrecord.

step1: Load the model using ckpt file

step2: get the model end points to run predictions; similar to the link above except removing the `:0`

step3: use placeholder to feed the numpy array (your images)

Apart from this you can convert the trained model into a frozen model [convert to frozen model](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/export_inference_graph.py)and follow the same step as described in the above link.